# How to check if all child processes ended?

Tags: c, pthreads, fork, child-process, pid

I am trying to create an assignment where I want to check if all child process created by students have exited. As I am not calling fork, I don't have access to thread ids. Is there a way to check if the current process doesn't have any children without knowing thread ids of child processes created?

I checked many questions but every solution consists of the use of return value from the fork call. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call

```
int st = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
```

The first argument tells `waitpid()` to wait for any child process to exit, not for a specific pid.

The third argument is a flag, that makes `waitpid()` return immediately instead of blocking.

Now there are three possible outcomes:

- return value is `-1` and `errno` is `ECHILD`: this means, that there is no child process present at all
- return value is `>0`: this denotes, that a child has exited in the past, but the return value was not yet collected (a so-called *zombie* process). Now iterate the process (call `waitpid()` again).
- return value is `0`: in this case, there are child processes available that are still running.

This should cover all cases you ask for.

Comment: AFAICT, the students can create processes that will *not* be waited for with this approach, by simply `fork()`ing in their process.

Comment: @EOF The main question was:_Is there a way to check if the current process doesn't have any children without knowing thread ids of child processes created?_, which is extensively answered here, I think

Comment: But if you actually read the question it's clear that this won't work for the stated problem.

Comment: @EOF No, I think that you misunderstand the OP

Comment: Maybe, but to quote: "As I am not calling fork [...]" implies that *the students* are calling `fork()`. It seems difficult to imagine a situation where the students are calling `fork()`, but cannot call `fork()` in the child. If the stated goal of the question is to "check if all child process created by students have exited", then only a very narrow understanding of the question would make this a good answer.